# Convert Object[] to Array()

Tags: java, arrays

How to convert Object to array?

I have this code, but it is create new, clear Object

```
public Object[] toArray() {
        return toArray(new Object[size()]);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. What exactly do you have, and what exactly do you want to convert it to.

Comment: What is the Object you are trying to convert?

Comment: What a marvellous piece of circular code :)

Comment: Could you provide more info on what you try to achieve? Are you implementing a Collection, a List? Where is the method toArray(Object[]) implemented?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik  bwahahahaha ,lol

Comment: i dont even understand what the person is asking ??  omg

Comment: You want to return Object[].  Anything you want to convert from??  Or do you just want to return an empty array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use

```
List<Object> object = Arrays.asList(objects);
```

and set it to type that you need or you can use something like this

```
public ArrayList<Object> toArray(Object[] object){
    ArrayList<Object> array = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for(Object obj : object){
        array.add(obj);
    }
    return array;
}
```

with also changing object type to something you need.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create an array of Objects do this:

```
Object[] objArray = new Object[size]; //with size is of type int
```

Comment: Does not change to array..